# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Th

Tags: reactjs

act.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
```

Comment: Please provide some more code so that it would be helpful to identify the cause

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Comment: import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import About from "./routes/About";
import Contact from "./routes/Contact";
import Project from "./routes/Project";

import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path="/project" element={<Project/>} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

Comment: You may have declared some state variable outside in any of this component.Move the state declaration inside the function